# Getting a submit selection into a variable with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-events

I am making a condition that verifies some class and depending on the value, the respectable submit input is stored into a variable:

```
_btnAjax = "";

if (_aVar.hasClass("one")) {
    _btnAjax = $("#one");
}
if (_aVar.hasClass("two")) {
    _btnAjax = $("#two");
}
```

and then, using the `.on('click' function(e){});` on that variable:

```
_btnAjax.on('click', function(e) {
     // some Ajax
}
```

The problem is that I receive the error `TypeError: _btnAjax.on is not a function`

I already made exactly the same thing on a `<li></li>`, but either `<button></button>` or `<input type='submit'/>` don't work.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that fails is because neither of your two conditions are true.

For example, if `_aVar` does not have a class of `one` AND it does not have a class of `two` then `_btnAjax` is a string in your code.

Double check that your UI has the right classes.

In addition, make sure you handle the other case.

Try writing your code more like this:

```
var _btnAjax;

if (_aVar.hasClass("one")) {
    _btnAjax = $("#one");
} else if (_aVar.hasClass("two")) {
    _btnAjax = $("#two");
} else {
    // Do something to handle the fact that neither case was true.
    //  You can return early, throw an error, or set _btnAjax to
    //  an empty jQuery object.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use a jQuery function (.on)
Try this:

```
$(_btnAjax).on('click', function(e) {
    // some ajax
}
```

Although I think you should use a id or class selector like:

```
// selector should be whatever your button has as id or class property.
// (preferably an id since this won't conflict with other classes)
$('#btnAjax').on('click', function(e) {
    // some ajax
}
```

Comment: I'm doing it like this because I have two forms and I don't want to repeat the code. The first suggestion worked, it didn't show the error but it also didn't make the Ajax to work, it works if I just put as the second suggestion.

Comment: Ok, so your issue is fixed then?